# How do I use nginx rewrite rules to point to an anchor?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, anchor

I'm running a website where I use rewrite rules for help topics sent from client software.
Now all of this works fine, except for one situation: if I want to jump to an anchor in a page to immediately jump to a specific section, nginx throws a 404 instead of using the redirect.

This works:

```
rewrite ^/support/prefs-content$ /support/prefs-content.shtml;
```

But this doesn't:

```
rewrite ^/support/prefs-fonts-and-colors$ /support/prefs-content.shtml#Fonts_and_Colors;
```

Using a full url (scheme+host+path+anchor) also works, but that's not a solution, the target URL must be relative.

Is there a way to do this kind of rewrite with an anchor?

Comment: Use quotes. `#` is a start of comment in nginx's config.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. nginx apparently tries to open the entire `/support/prefs-content.shtml#Fonts_and_Colors` string as a file with open(), which fails.

Comment: How, Alexey? Remember the path resolution has to be relative.